# android Bezier curve Chart

Tags: android, charts, bezier

i want draw a chart like this

[image]

but i got like this

[image]

the red point is my data point

anyone can help me ?

here is my code :

```
private void initFeedPath(List<Point> points,boolean circular) {

    feedPath.reset();

    feedPath.moveTo(points.get(0).x, points.get(0).y);

    int length = points.size();
    if (circular) {
        length -= 2;
    }

    PointF p1 = new PointF();
    PointF p2 = new PointF();
    PointF p3 = new PointF();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {

        int nextIndex = i + 1 < length ? i + 1 : i;
        int nextNextIndex = i + 2 < length ? i + 2 : nextIndex;

        calc(points, p1, i, nextIndex, mSecondMultiplier);

        p2.x = points.get(nextIndex).x;
        p2.y = points.get(nextIndex).y;

        calc(points, p3, nextIndex, nextNextIndex, mFirstMultiplier);
        // From last point, approaching x1/y1 and x2/y2 and ends up at x3/y3
        feedPath.cubicTo(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y);

    }


    if (circular) {

        for (int i = length; i < length + 2; i += 1) {
            feedPath.lineTo(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y);
        }

        feedPath.lineTo(points.get(0).x, points.get(0).y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reduce your example. Show the first 7 points in your graph, list what the actual coordinates are, and what you expected that to do. Then explain why you think your code should effect that. And in the process of updating your post with all that information is it *entirely* likely that you hit upon the answer yourself because you're running through the process of proper debugging. But you don't, also sketch the graph you did expect (don't borrow one from paper.js with different coordinates =)

Comment: i think i have solved the problem by add a point(last.x,height) at last position;thanks for the answer ,thank u

Comment: As an expert on bezier curves, I have no idea why that would even remotely fix the issue you showed pictures of, so it'll be worth either deleting the question, or rewriting it to a better form and then writing an answer to it yourself with an explanation of why that works =)